# Rails - routing error on delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**UPDATE** rephrased after learning

I have extended my app with a new model called 'tag' (very similar set up as with comments in blog).

Intended outcome: the user to stay on the page when clicking the link_to button to delete a tag; I now get an routing error (below) and I don't understand why.

> No route matches [DELETE] "/annotations/7/tags"

The TAG list is added to the view for ANNOTATIONS like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: white;  word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 0.9em;">
    <table id="tags" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Tag</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% @annotation.tags.each do |tag| %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= tag.content %></td>
                    <td><%#= tag.tagtype_id | tag.tagtype.typeoftag %></td>
                    <td><%= link_to '', [tag.annotation, tag], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Please confirm deletion!' }, :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-remove" %></td>
                </tr>
            <% end -%>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

These are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'dashboard#index'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, :documenttypes, :tagtypes

  resources :documents do
    resources :tags
    get "pdf", on: :member 

  end

  resources :annotations do
    resources :comments, :tags
    get "pdf", on: :member

end

get "annotations/:id/annotate" => "annotations#annotate", as: 'annotate'
get "angular_test", to: "angular_test#index"

mount PdfjsViewer::Rails::Engine => "/pdfjs", as: 'pdfs'
```

And the tags.controller

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController

def create
@annotation = Annotation.find(params[:annotation_id])
@comment = @annotation.tags.create(tag_params)
redirect_to annotation_path(@annotation)
end

def destroy
  @annotation = Annotation.find(params[:annotation_id])
  @comment = @annotation.tags.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy
  redirect_to annotate_path(@annotation)
end

private
 def tag_params
   params.require(:tag).permit(:content, :location, :tagtype_id)
 end

end
```

**UPDATE**
The table in the view always has an empty row, which I cannot delete. I then get the routing error. With rows that were created when adding a tag, this does not happen and I can delete them. Why am I getting an empty row?

Comment: Yes, you can do it without Jquery, in plain javascript.

Comment: And without plain JS, just using rails / ruby / erb?

Comment: yes, with page reloading.

Comment: Well, my page is on annotating a pdf. And one row is one tag. So, reloading would loose the other tags - no?

Comment: what's depend on how you generate this page.

Comment: okay - where could I find more doc on this please? Am new to rails / ruby (finding that most of what I look for is there ;-) (yet, need a way to find it).

Comment: you can find any doc in the google

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done using AJAX (asynchronously), all you need to do is to have your destroy action to respond to javascript. You can do that by adding the remote option to the link for the deletion as below:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Delete', [tag.annotation, tag], method: :delete, remote: true, data: { confirm: 'Please confirm deletion!' }, :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-remove" %></td>
```

The `remote: true` option makes the request AJAX. Now on the controller side you need to respond with the resulting javascript code that you want to execute, probably hiding this row that you want to delete.

In the views folder, under the tags controller you need to create a file called destroy.js and in this file you specify the code that you want to be executed for handling this to hide for example that row.

Comment: have it working without the AJAX (required the right redirect_to on the tags controller). What remains is the empty row (no tag exists) that appears (see bottom update) always and that I can't delete either (routing error).